# Accuracy of Neural network Output-Matlab ANN Toolbox

Tags: matlab, pattern-recognition

I'm relatively new to Matlab ANN Toolbox. I am training the NN with pattern recognition and target matrix of 3x8670 containing 1s and 0s, using one hidden layer, 40 neurons and the rest with default settings. When I get the simulated output for new set of inputs, then the values are around 0 and 1. I then arrange them in descending order and choose a fixed number(which is known to me) out of 8670 observations to be 1 and rest to be zero.

Every time I run the program, the first row of the simulated output always has close to 100% accuracy and the following rows dont exhibit the same kind of accuracy.

Is there a logical explanation in general? I understand that answering this query conclusively might require the understanding of program and problem, but its made of of several functions to clearly explain. Can I make some changes in the training to get consistence output?

If you have any suggestions please share it with me.

Thanks,

Nishant

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is not clear for me. For example, what you mean by: "I then arrange them in descending order and choose a fixed number ..."

As I understand, you did not get appropriate output from your NN as compared to the real target. I mean, your output from NN is difference than target. If so, there are different possibilities which should be considered:

1. How do you divide training/test/validation sets for training phase? The most division should be assigned to training (around 75%) and rest for test/validation.
2. How is your training data set? Can it support most scenarios as you expected? If your trained data set is not somewhat similar to your test data sets (e.g., you have some new records/samples in the test data set which had not (near) appear in the training phase, it explains as 'outlier' and NN cannot work efficiently with these types of samples, so you need clustering approach not NN classification approach), your results from NN is out-of-range and NN cannot provide ideal accuracy as you need. NN is good for those data set training, where there is no very difference between training and test data sets. Otherwise, NN is not appropriate.
3. Sometimes you have an appropriate training data set, but the problem is training itself. In this condition, you need other types of NN, because feed-forward NNs such as MLP cannot work with compacted and not well-separated regions of data very well. You need strong function approximation such as RBF and SVM.